# Textmate: Start with project drawer open AND files open

Tags: textmate

Is there a way to start a new instance of Textmate with the project drawer open AND 1 or more files open?

It is acceptable if the files or project drawer are opened AFTER Textmate starts as long as it is accomplished with no additional user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this by setting up a Textmate project. A Textmate project (assuming it works pretty similar to a SublimeText project) is a file somewhere on you computer, this file has a bunch of metadata about your project, for instance which folders to keep in the project drawer (you may also have other project-specific settings like theme, indentation settings etc.). If you open up a project, the project drawer will open automatically with the folders specified in the project file.

You can find some good information about this over [here at the Textmate manual](https://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files)

If you're comfortable with the Terminal, and have the `mate` command setup, you can do this to start a new project:

```
$ cd my_project
$ mate .
```

That will startup the directory structure you have in `my_project` as a new Textmate project. Otherwise you can save your current project in the context menu from TM.

As with the default expanding/collapsing of folders within your project, and default opening of files - I'm not quite sure about how Textmate handles it for projects, I'm used to SublimeText these days. SublimeText works pretty much the same as Textmate and they have the features you are describing with certain files defaultly open when you open the program.